# How to convert C++ reference- and pointer returns to C++/CLR

Tags: c++, migration, clr

I have to convert a lot of C++ code to C++/CLR for use by a front-end written in C#.

What would be appropriate declarations of these 2 C++ methods in C++/CLR ?

```
MyClass& MyMethod1();

MyClass* MyMethod2();
```

The original code was written in Embarcadero XE2, now the environment is visualC++
Since there is so much code to convert I really would like to keep as much as possible. Also a commercial component (Embarcadero) that was used in the original code is now a CLR component so I pretty much have to convert the old code to C++/CLR.

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience with using C++ CLI with C#-written .Net application. My advice is not to convert the whole C++ library but to write interface wrappers, e.g:

```
// existing unmanaged code
class UnmanagedClass
{
public:
    void SomeMethod();
};

// a C++ CLR
ref class ManagedWrapper
{
public:
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        obj->SomeMethod();
    }

private:
    UnmanagedClass* object;
};
```

Yes, there is still a lot of work (you'll need to create wrappers for all interface enities, parameters, enums, etc. But it's still less work than to migrate all the code.

Answer (score 0):

The both functions should return handles to a reference type, i.e.

```
ref class SomeClass
{
public:
    MyClass ^MyMethod1()
    {
        return gcnew MyClass();
    }

    MyClass ^MyMethod2()
    {
        return gcnew MyClass();
    }
};
```

This will be equivalent to a pointer to a class object.